# Why is my return values keep giving me 0 on a random congruential number generator program?

Tags: c#, loops, random

So I'm creating a simple random congruential number generator. It's the first time I'm using windows forms and for some reason the results keep giving me 0. Can someone tell me what's going on?

What my program is doing is the user adds the seed the a, c, mod value, and how many times it wants to iterate random numbers. But when I click generate it just gives me 0's in each new line depending how much I want it to iterate. At least I know the iteration is correct.

```
namespace Metodos
{
    public partial class Mixto : Form
    {
        public Mixto()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bttnGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int seed, a, c, mod, it, numrand, residuo;
            float division;

            seed = Convert.ToInt32(txtSeed.Text);
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txtA.Text);
            c = Convert.ToInt32(txtC.Text);
            mod = Convert.ToInt32(txtMod.Text);
            it = Convert.ToInt32(txtIt.Text);

            for (int i = 1; i <= it; i++)
            {
                string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
                numrand = seed * a + c;
                residuo = numrand % mod;
                division = residuo / mod;
                residuo = seed;
                results.Text = results.Text + newLine + division.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void bttnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            results.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an integer division on this line:

```
division = residuo / mod;
```

Therefore, if your actual result is anything less than `0` (say, `0.34`), you'd get the value `0` to your `division`.

Instead, do

```
division = (float)residuo / mod;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
residuo = numrand % mod;

division = residuo / mod;
```

On these two lines, you set `residuo` equal to the modulo (remainder) of a division. You then divide this remainder by `mod`. `residuo` will ALWAYS be less than `mod` at this step (by it's nature of being a remainder of a division with the same divisor). As it's integer division, this will always result in 0. You likely need to substitute `numrand` for `residuo` on line 2

```
residuo = seed;
```

I think this line may be backwards as well. I suspect you intended to modify the seed for the next iteration?

Making these two changes, as below, I get something that seems to work

```
  int seed, a, c, mod, it, numrand, residuo;
  float division;

  seed = 23;
  a = 34 ;
  c = 17;
  mod = 45;
  it = 100;




  for (int i = 1; i <= it; i++) {
    string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

    numrand = seed * a + c;

    residuo = numrand % mod;

    division = numrand / mod;

    //residuo = seed;
    seed = residuo;

    Console.WriteLine("{2}",numrand, residuo, division);

  }

Output:
10
7
6
14
25
10
32
29
29
3
13
33
21
18
17
26
2
22
10
7
6
14
25
```